# Why my Django app on heroku displays Server Error (500) for default page?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have my django  app hosted with heroku.
However without anything being changed from my side default page stopped working in last few weeks.This is how I define it in my url file:

```
url(r'^$', views.leaseterm_list, name="leaseterm_list"),
```

This is the message in the log

> 2017-07-15T10:41:33.762772+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/" host=*******.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=0c8faedf-4c9f-4340-941c-ff6c476052d4 fwd="70.55.61.228"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=205ms status=500 bytes=253
>   protocol=https

Any idea what is going on? I assume heroku changed something on their side.

Comment: May be your problem is referenced here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28014987/4465743

Comment: it says 404 not 500 right? You installed proper Logging for the project? Where is the 404 comping from? Staticfiles run normal on the rest go the site?

Comment: @ Rajan Chahan Nope it works with PostgresDB

Comment: @hansTheFranz sorry I tried to duplicate the issue on different hosting wrong log posted originally . It is actually 500 . I updated the log.

Comment: There should be a log of the WGSI server showing the actual error traceback.

Comment: @ Klaus D.  any idea how can i get to this log on heroku?

Comment: @Klaus D.  You are right even the error is 500 when I did setup the Debug to true I got some other error in my range method. It was data related .Thanks

Comment: The error 500 is a general error code given by webservers for all exceptions. You don't want outsiders to see your real error message.